# Can a non-EU citizen contractor travel to the UK for work purposes without obtaining a permit?

Tags: united-kingdom, eu, working

I'm a third-country national who is a self-employed permanent resident in the Czech Republic. As far as I'm aware, EU companies are free to post workers to other EU countries, [even if those workers are non-EU citizens](http://eulawanalysis.blogspot.cz/2014/09/posting-third-country-workers-within-eu.html). I am also aware that even non-EU companies regularly send out their employees to the EU for "business meetings", which can include some degree of work done on-site for the parent company.

Being a self-employed software engineering consultant, am I allowed to sign a contract with a company located in the UK (signed by myself as a business, not as a physical person) and then proceed to travel to the UK visa-free to work for said company as an external employee? My passport allows me visa-free access to the UK, so normally I won't need to apply for an entry clearance beforehand.

Links to official UK government websites explaining the limits to what an EU contractor may do within the UK (without a work permit) would be appreciated. I am aware that Brexit would complicate things in the future, but for now all previous EU laws are still in effect.

Comment: "Self-employed" could mean a few different things.  Have you organized a legal entity in the EU?  If not, I would be surprised if your being an EU resident qualifies you as "an EU company."

Comment: @phoog I have a sole proprietorship. It's a business entity like any other.

Comment: In US tax terminology, "sole proprietorship" describes (among others) someone who operates a business without incorporating or forming any other sort of legal entity.

Comment: @phoog I have a tax number and can become a VAT payer if needed. It's a corporation.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the [EUN04 document](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/non-eea-and-swiss-nationals-working-in-the-eu-eun04). It states that:

> En established non-EEA employee of an EU company in the EU can come to the UK to provide a service on behalf of the company without a work permit. Entry clearance is mandatory for both visa and non-visa nationals. Entry clearance is issued gratis.
>
> The requirements to be met by the employee are that they:
>
> - are lawfully resident in the EU Member State in which the employer is established;
> - are lawfully and habitually employed by an employer who is temporarily providing a service in the UK;
> - do not intend to take any other employment;
> - intend to leave the UK at the end of the period during which his employer is providing the service.

I couldn't really find more on how you would obtain the visa and entry clearance to actually use this route and not rely to one of the usual non-EEA/Swiss visas.

I found the link to this document on the governments [information site for posted workers](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/temporary-work-in-other-eu-countries).